# Why isn't .CommandText recognising the LIKE statement like it does in a Query in sqldeveloper?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, oracle

I'm using a CommandText to get some data back from a database, basically I have three parameters that are passed from a service that have a value of:

```
ORIG_LOC = STPX

PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEp = 18:15

uwttid = 631D62MW26
```

This is all good and fine, I have this command text statement.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS WHERE TRAIN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES WHERE ORIG_LOC ='" + ORIG_LOC + "' AND UWTTID ='" + uwttid + "' AND PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP LIKE '%" + PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP + "%')";
```

which just seems to return null and gives me no results, however if I get rid of the last part and just use this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS WHERE TRAIN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES WHERE ORIG_LOC ='" + ORIG_LOC + "' AND UWTTID ='" + uwttid + "')";
```

It returns all the necessary data. This is frustrating because this command works in sqldeveloper and returns all the necessary tables, but when I use it in my statement at the top with variables with the same value as what I have set below, it doesn't return any results. It's having problems with the LIKE statement and I have no idea why.

The below statement is what I can use in sqldeveloper to query my database and it returns the exact results the table I need, but when using LIKE in C# in a .CommandText it just doesn't search it the same way it does querying it in sqldeveloper.

```
SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS rs WHERE rs.TRAIN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT ds.TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES ds WHERE ds.UWTTID = '631D62MW26' AND ds.ORIG_LOC = 'STPX' AND ds.PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP LIKE '%18:15%');
```

Here you can see that the variables I'm passing in the CommandText have the same values, and 2/3 work but when I try to use the LIKE statement for PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP it just doesn't work.

[image]

This is the row I'm trying to query in my Oracle database so you can see that it does actually exist.
[image]

**SUMMARISED VERSION:**
So basically if this is confusing and doesn't make sense, what I'm really asking is. Why doesn't this statement work?

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS WHERE TRAIN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES WHERE ORIG_LOC ='" + ORIG_LOC + "' AND UWTTID ='" + uwttid + "' AND PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP LIKE '%" + PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP + "%')";
```

When this identical one works in SQLDEVELOPER as a query?

```
 SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS rs WHERE rs.TRAIN_ID = (SELECT ds.TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES ds WHERE ds.UWTTID = '631D62MW26' AND ds.ORIG_LOC = 'STPX' AND ds.PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP LIKE '%18:15%');
```

Not sure if relevant, but this is the method it's being used in: This method works when I get rid of the PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP part but doesn't work when using it.

```
  public ServiceResponse GetReservations(string uwttid, string ORIG_LOC, string PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP)
    {
        ServiceResponse sR = new ServiceResponse();

        JavaScriptSerializer jscript = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        try
        {
            string dataSource = "Data Source=GMOB; User Id=Firenze; Password=Dumbledore";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(dataSource);
            List<Reservations> reservationsList = new List<Reservations>();
            conn.Open();


                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS WHERE TRAIN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES WHERE ORIG_LOC ='" + ORIG_LOC + "' AND UWTTID ='" + uwttid + "' AND PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP LIKE '%" + PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP + "%')";


                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Reservations reservations = new Reservations();
                    var spacing = " - ";
                    var bracket1 = " (";
                    var bracket2 = ")";
                    reservations.Coach = dr["COACH_LETTER"].ToString();
                    reservations.Seat = dr["SEAT_NUM"].ToString() + dr["SEAT_TYPE"].ToString() + bracket1 + dr["POSITION"].ToString() + bracket2;
                    reservations.Class = dr["CLASS"].ToString();
                    reservations.Leg = dr["LOC_START"].ToString() + spacing + dr["LOC_END"].ToString();
                    reservations.Notes = dr["NOTES"].ToString();
                    reservationsList.Add(reservations);
                }
                dr.Close();
                conn.Dispose();

            sR.DataResponse = jscript.Serialize(reservationsList);
            return sR;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.LogError("getreservations" + ex.ToString());
            sR.Message = "Failed";
            return sR;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Eugh, that's horrible; SQL injection heaven. If you regularly write data access code like this: ***stop now*** - go back and fix it all (use parameters instead of concatenation): your code needs immediate attention, and is **hugely** susceptible to malicious abuse.

Comment: We seem to have a really different notion of identical. Could you kindly ensure both really are identical? HINT: one uses 'DISTINCT', the other not; one has table aliases, the other doesn't (which might be important, depending on your schema).

Also - since your code seems to be about difference in how SQL commands are executed between C# and SqlDeveloper, could you kindly try to isolate the least amount of code to show your problem? Is error handling, javascript serialization, etc. really relevant here?

Comment: I forgot to get rid of the distinct sorry, it doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Please can you indicate the **exact** value of `cmd.CommandText` immediately before you execute the query? (unrelated, but you should also *really* be using `using` there)

Comment: I find it unlikely that this `LIKE` query has ever worked correctly... `LIKE` on a *date/time* column is simply: *wrong*

Comment: Is there an alternative way of searching for the time? My problem is that the parameter only passes '18:15' when the actual record in the table is '26/09/14 18:15:00' @MarcGravell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an *answer* as such, but **please, please** use parameters (and `using`):

```
List<Reservations> reservationsList = new List<Reservations>();
using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(dataSource))
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RESERVED_SEATS WHERE TRAIN_ID = (SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_ID FROM DAILY_SCHEDULES WHERE ORIG_LOC = :ORIG_LOC AND UWTTID = :UWTTID AND PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP LIKE '%' + :PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP + '%')";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ORIG_LOC", ORIG_LOC);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UWTTID", uwttid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP", PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP);

    using(OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {        
        while (dr.Read()) {...}
    }
}
sR.DataResponse = jscript.Serialize(reservationsList);
```

Comment: I did try parameterising, but couldn't get it work. I see now that I had the commandtext all wrong. I'll do that in the future thank you

Comment: also, I tried using AddWithValue previously and it said was I missing an assembly reference, but there aren't any other references and I googled it and said that Oracle didn't support AddWithValue and that I should use Add(new OracleParameter) instead?

Comment: @Shaun there are a myriad ways of adding parameters; the point is: add them as parameters. How: is an implementation detail.

Comment: I've added the parameters, I think the problem is that I'm trying to pass a string to my database when 'PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP' is actually a DateTime, I'm trying to convert my PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP which only ever has a value of something like '18:15' to 26/09/14 18:15:00. The date being the Date.Today and the time being my PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP string + :00 but I can't figure out how to do that. Could you help me out?

Comment: @Shaun and again I say: I don't think it is reasonable to *expect* that to work - and it *certainly* isn't reasonable to expect it to be *efficient*. A date/time **is just a number**. It isn't "like" *anything*, natively. If you want to search on just the time part of a composite date/time, IMO you should be storing the date part and time part separately, and then doing a range query on `SecondsIntoDay` or `MinutesIntoDay` or whatever you call the time part. If you can *make it work* with `like`, then fine: good luck. But that isn't the best choice IMHO.

Comment: I see. I took your advise of not using a like and tried this instead:
DateTime PLAN_WRK = DateTime.Today;
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP);
PLAN_WRK = PLAN_WRK + time;

This returns a format of '26/09/2014 18:15:00' which is exactly how it is in my database, so when I run "AND PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP = :PLAN_WRK)" it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a sample query just to make sure the c# part is doing right :
You may test this as well to see if you can run it without any problem:
Here I am trying to select using a command like below :
First Method , Not suggested :

```
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(YourConnectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
        {
            string query = string.Format("select * from table1 where id3 LIKE '{0}'", "%18:15%");
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            var tb = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(tb);

        }
    }
```

This selects just fine. 
Now If you need to use parameters use it in this way :

```
  using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(YourConnectionString))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
        {
            string query = "select * from table1 where id3 LIKE :var";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("var", "%18:15%");
            cmd.Connection = con;

            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            var tb = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(tb);

        }
    }
```

runs just fine as well .

And this is the sample data query that i made to test this :

```
CREATE TABLE test.TABLE1 (
  ID  NUMBER(10, 0),
  ID2 NVARCHAR2(50),
  ID3 NVARCHAR2(50)
)
TABLESPACE USERS
STORAGE (INITIAL 64 K
         NEXT 1 M
         MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED)
LOGGING;
```

Edit:
If your problem is to convert your string into a DateTime variable, you can simply use `DateTime.Parse()` like this :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("18:15");
```

this will give you a datetime variable which holds :

```
9/26/2014 18:15:00
```

You might also have a look at [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are dealing with non standard date time string

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but this wasn't quite the problem. I've realised since I'm trying to pass it a string when it wants a datetime I've got a string named 'PLAN_WRK_ORIG_DEP' that has a value of '18:15' in it. I need to convert it to a datetime that has this format: 26/09/14 18:15:00 
The time has to be whatever the string's value is plus a :00 on the end and the date must be todays date. How would I even go about this? Obviously something to do with DateTime.now but how could I assign the second part's time to my string's value?

Comment: use DateTime.Parse() then. See the answer